# How do I set the alpha of all Principled BSDF nodes with Python?

Tags: python, materials

[image]

I want to reset the alpha of all Principled BSDF nodes to 1.0 with a Python script, since it would be cumbersome to change the values all by hand.

Comment: The reset button is from the node wrangler add-on. You can take a look how they implemented it in `node_wrangler.py` in the class `NWResetNodes`. What particular part are you currently struggling with?

Comment: with the alpha it is set to 0 for every materials, i want to change to 1 (max)

Answer (score 3):

The materials of the blend-file can be accessed through [`bpy.data.materials`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.materials) regardless which scene they are being used in. For a given material the nodes can be access through the material's [`node_tree`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Material.html#bpy.types.Material.node_tree). In order to ensure that you are working on the right [`node`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html#bpy.types.Node), you can check its `bl_idname`. For Principled BSDFs the `bl_idname` is the string `"ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled"`. Since alpha is an input value of the node, it is accessed through the [`inputs`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html#bpy.types.Node.inputs) and its value is set through [`default_value`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeSocketFloat.html#bpy.types.NodeSocketFloat.default_value).

```
import bpy

# Iterate through all materials
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    # Some materials do not use nodes and thus don't have a node tree, skip them
    if mat.node_tree is None:
        continue
    # Get the nodes from the current material
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    # Iterate through all nodes
    for node in nodes:
        # Check if the node is a Principled BSDF
        if node.bl_idname == "ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled":
            # If it is, set the alpha to 1.0
            node.inputs["Alpha"].default_value = 1.0
```

Comment: thanks a lot bruh

Comment: @JoelJose if the answer solved your problem you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it. That way other users will know which answer worked for you.